# Как сделать "умный ответ бота"?

Tags: api

Хочу что бы когда человек ввёл текст бот ответил реалистично, слышал что то про Chat api, но ничего не нашёл про это

Comment: Уточните, на каком языке вы создаёте бота и замените метку `api` на соответствующую. Например `api + python -> pyhon api`

Answer (score 2):

Может быть не очень в тему, но первым шагом к реалистичному боту будет совсем другой бот:

Люди пишут боту сообщение. Он это сообщение запоминает и отправляет такое-же сообщение другим людям, то что они отвечают он запоминает. Т.е. у него формируется база из готовых вопросов-ответов. При том, что количество ответов всегда больше вопросов. Дальше эту всю кашу можно будет отмодерировать в ручном или автоматическом режиме. Пользуясь такой базой из вопросов-ответов можно залепить бота с реалистичными ответами. Разговор, конечно, с таким ботом далеко не зайдет, но иной раз удивить может

Не уверен, что я ответил на ваш вопрос, но думаю это прикольно и не сложно